# What is the drawback of having a dictionary of delegates per instance?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-core

I am developing an Asp.net Core 2 MVC project as follows. I will keep the code snippet as simple as possible by removing the parts that we should be familiar with.

- Entity model

  ```
  public class Customer
  {
      public string Id { get; set; }
      public string CompanyName { get; set; }
      public string ContactName { get; set; }
      public string Country { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Database context

  ```
  public class AppDbContext : DbContext
  {
      public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
      public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
  }
  ```
- Auxiliary class for searching by country, company name, and others

  ```
  public class Search
  {
      public enum Options
      {
          [Display(Name="By Country")]
          ByCountry = 1,
          [Display(Name = "By Company Name")]
          ByCompanyName = 2,
          // in the future there will be other items appended   
      }

      public AppDbContext Context { get; }
      public IDictionary<Options, Func<string, IEnumerable<Customer>>> SearchMethods { get; }

      public Search(AppDbContext context)
      {
          Context = context;
          SearchMethods =
              new Dictionary<Options, Func<string, IEnumerable<Customer>>>()
              {
                  [Options.ByCountry] = x => Context.Customers
                             .Where(c => c.Country.ToLower().Contains(x.ToLower()))
                             .ToList(),

                  [Options.ByCompanyName] = x => Context.Customers
                             .Where(c => c.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(x.ToLower()))
                             .ToList()

                  // in the future there will be other items appended 
              };
      }        
  }
  ```

`Search` allows me to avoid hard-coded literal string in both controllers and views. Here are the examples:

- Controller

  ```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
      public Search S { get; }
      public HomeController(Search s) => S = s;

      [HttpPost]
      public IActionResult Search(string criteria, Search.Options searchBy)
          => View(S.SearchMethods[searchBy](criteria));

  }
  ```
- View

  ```
  <input name="criteria" />
  <select name="searchBy" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Search.Options>()"></select>
  ```

## Questions

I realize that gradually adding new elements to `Options` enumeration and adding new items to `SearchMethods` dictionary properties will not produce versioning issue as long as I can make sure the elements of `Options` are kept numerically in the same orders.

Now my concern is whether there are any drawbacks with this approach? For example about performance issue, scalability issue because there is an instance of dictionary `SearchMethods` per instance of `Search`.

Any comments and suggestions are welcome.

## Edit

It is the last decision I made so far. I converted the registration with a dictionary  to a lookup with `switch` as follows.

```
    public class Search
    {
        public enum Options
        {
            [Display(Name = "By Country")]
            ByCountry = 1,
            [Display(Name = "By Company Name")]
            ByCompanyName = 2,
            [Display(Name = "By Contact Name")]
            ByContactName = 3
        }

        public AppDbContext Context { get; }
        public Search(AppDbContext context) => Context = context;

        public IEnumerable<Customer> Filter(string criteria, Options options)
        {
            IEnumerable<Customer> customers = Context.Customers;
            string lowCriteria = criteria.ToLower();
            switch (options)
            {
                case Options.ByCountry:
                    customers = customers.Where(c => c.Country.ToLower().Contains(lowCriteria));
                    break;
                case Options.ByCompanyName:
                    customers = customers.Where(c => c.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(lowCriteria));
                    break;
                case Options.ByContactName:
                    customers = customers.Where(c => c.ContactName.ToLower().Contains(lowCriteria));
                    break;
            }
            return customers.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Retrieving all data to do filtering in the UI is generally not a good approach. You should be doing as much filtering as possible in the DB query itself. All you really do with this approach is add a higher memory footprint, network bandwidth and CPU cycles to the mix. About the only case where it makes sense would be if you had really poor connection to the DB or a realy weak DB server. But at that point, a Distributed Database Design would propably be better anywway.

Comment: Why are you even using a dictionary of query methods? Why don’t you just add these query types as individual method on your `Search` type?

Comment: @poke: Because I don't want the consumer of `Search` to manually map `Options` item to the corresponding query method. In other words, I want the `Search` class does apply the first principle in SOLID, i.e., Single Responsibility Principle. Mapping should be inside `Search` class. 

If I convert the `SearchMethods` items as methods of `Search` then the controller action method `Search` must do the mapping with `switch`.
Thank you.

Comment: You could still use actual methods instead of delegates, also to increase testability and maintainability. And you should make the mapping static, to avoid the dictionary creation overhead on every request. Also also, to avoid ending up with many search options for every single combination, you could use flags instead and make your queries naturally combine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use actual methods to make the class overall easier to read and to also allow you to use those queries directly, e.g. for testing:

```
public class Search
{
    public AppDbContext Context { get; }
    public IDictionary<Options, Func<string, IEnumerable<Customer>>> SearchMethods { get; }

    public Search(AppDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        SearchMethods = new Dictionary<Options, Func<string, IEnumerable<Customer>>>()
        {
            [Options.ByCountry] = GetByCountry,
            [Options.ByCompanyName] = GetByCompanyName,
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetByCountry (string countryName)
    {
        return Context.Customers
           .Where(c => c.Country.ToLower().Contains(countryName.ToLower()))
           .ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetByCompanyName (string companyName)
    {
        return Context.Customers
            .Where(c => c.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(companyName.ToLower()))
            .ToList()
    }
}
```

This still does have the overhead of creating a (basically constant) dictionary for each `Search` instance though, which means on every request for scoped services.

We can avoid that by having a static lookup. Unfortunately, we can only do this for static methods, so we have to change them around a bit to take the database context as well. And we add a utility method to the `Search` instance:

```
public class Search
{
    private static IDictionary<Options, Func<AppDbContext, string, IEnumerable<Customer>>> _searchMethods { get; }

    public AppDbContext Context { get; }

    static Search()
    {
        _searchMethods = new Dictionary<Options, Func<AppDbContext, string, IEnumerable<Customer>>>()
        {
            [Options.ByCountry] = GetByCountry,
            [Options.ByCompanyName] = GetByCompanyName,
        };
    }

    public Search(AppDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> Get(Options query, string argument)
        => _searchMethods[query](Context, argument);

    public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetByCountry (AppDbContext context, string countryName)
    {
        return context.Customers
           .Where(c => c.Country.ToLower().Contains(countryName.ToLower()))
           .ToList();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetByCompanyName (AppDbContext context, string companyName)
    {
        return context.Customers
            .Where(c => c.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(companyName.ToLower()))
            .ToList()
    }
}
```